# as_json only working for some attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

It appears that as_json is working for some of my attributes, but not all. Could someone tell me if anything here looks wrong? It's the "type" attribute that isn't working.

```
def as_json(options = {})
  {
    id: self.id, 
    type: self.type,
    name: self.name 
    }
  end
```

---

```
 def index
    @streams = @current_user.streams
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.json { render :json => @streams.as_json }
    end    
  end
```

Comment: What isn't exactly working? What is your model definition? What are you expecting?

Comment: @tirdadc Sorry should have been more clear- when I actually run streams.as_json in a debugger, the attribute "type" just doesn't show up. I'm expecting to see "type"=>some value

Comment: `type` is a reserved column name in Rails, for inheritance - are you changing the inheritance column?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with this implementation.  Most importantly, `#as_json` is incorrectly overridden, which means nothing is running through  the default `ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON#as_json` method.  You probably want to read the detailed documentation located here:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Assuming all those values are simply attributes on the object, you would want your `#as_json` method to look like:

```
def as_json(opts = {})
  super(opts.merge(only: [:id, :type, :name]))
end
```

If any of them are methods, rather than simply attributes, they would need to be included separately.

A minor point is that, when rendering an object to JSON using `render json: @streams`, you do not need to manually call `#as_json`.  This is done automatically as part of the rendering and is not something you need to worry about.